# Liquibase:generateChangeLog reports success but no changes listed

Tags: derby, liquibase

I'm trying to run generateChangeLog on an existing derby database. It has a number of tables in it.

```
c:\Projects\core\cams>java -jar lib\liquibase.jar --    classpath=derby.jar;derbyclient.jar --driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver --url="jdbc:derby:CAMSDB" --changeLogFile=db-changelog.xml --logLevel=debug --logFile=log.txt generateChangelog`
```

The resulting output indicates success:

```
INFO 13/03/15 14:27: liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.serializer.core
.json.JsonChangeLogSerializer as a Liquibase service because org.yaml.snake
yaml.representer.Representer is not in the classpath
INFO 13/03/15 14:27: liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.serializer.core
.yaml.YamlChangeLogSerializer as a Liquibase service because org.yaml.snake
yaml.representer.Representer is not in the classpath
Liquibase 'generateChangelog' Successful
```

The debug trace is:

```
DEBUG 13/03/15 14:27: liquibase: Connected to APP@jdbc:derby:CAMSDB
DEBUG 13/03/15 14:27: liquibase: Setting auto commit to false from true 
DEBUG 13/03/15 14:27: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select current schema from sysibm.sysdummy1
DEBUG 13/03/15 14:27: liquibase: Computed checksum for 1426256831398 as 0815fc1f3d5660bee0ff4ef70e42471d
INFO 13/03/15 14:27: liquibase: db-changelog.xml does not exist, creating
DEBUG 13/03/15 14:27: liquibase: MissingObjectChangeGenerator type order:     liquibase.structure.core.Catalog    liquibase.structure.core.Schema    liquibase.structure.core.Sequence    liquibase.structure.core.StoredProcedure    liquibase.structure.core.Table    liquibase.structure.core.Column    liquibase.structure.core.PrimaryKey    liquibase.structure.core.UniqueConstraint    liquibase.structure.core.ForeignKey    liquibase.structure.core.Index    liquibase.structure.core.View
DEBUG 13/03/15 14:27: liquibase: UnexpectedObjectChangeGenerator type order:         liquibase.structure.core.Catalog    liquibase.structure.core.ForeignKey    liquibase.structure.core.Schema    liquibase.structure.core.StoredProcedure    liquibase.structure.core.UniqueConstraint    liquibase.structure.core.View    liquibase.structure.core.Table    liquibase.structure.core.PrimaryKey    liquibase.structure.core.Column    liquibase.structure.core.Index    liquibase.structure.core.Sequence
DEBUG 13/03/15 14:27: liquibase: ChangedObjectChangeGenerator type order:     liquibase.structure.core.Catalog    liquibase.structure.core.ForeignKey    liquibase.structure.core.Schema    liquibase.structure.core.Sequence    liquibase.structure.core.StoredProcedure    liquibase.structure.core.Table    liquibase.structure.core.Column    liquibase.structure.core.PrimaryKey    liquibase.structure.core.Index    liquibase.structure.core.UniqueConstraint    liquibase.structure.core.View
INFO 13/03/15 14:27: liquibase: Shutting down derby connection: jdbc:derby:CAMSDB;shutdown=true
```

but the created xml file is substantially empty

Can anyone suggest anything to help me here?

Answer (score 0):

You missed put in snakeyaml jar into the classpath.The liquibase must have the sankeyaml jar.

```
java -jar lib/liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --classpath=lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:lib/snakeyaml-1.16.jar --changeLogFile=000-initial-schema.xml --url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db" --username=root --password= generateChangeLog
```

missing line

```
-classpath=lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:lib/snakeyaml-1.16.jar
```